# A real star riddle

Tags: riddle

500 are at my end,
500 are at my start,
but at my heart there are only 5.
The first letter and the first number make me complete:
Some consider me a king,
others consider me a real star.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Answer:

> David

Logic:

500 are at my end,
500 are at my start,

> D is 500 in roman numerals (start and end)

but at my heart there are only 5.

> V is 5 in roman numerals and at the heart of the word.

The first letter and the first number make me complete:

> First letter (A) and first number (i is 1 in roman numerals) finish off the name.

Some consider me a king,
others consider me a real star.

> David is a king in the bible, and the star of David is a symbol of Judaism.

Answer (score 4):

**I think The Answer is.....**

> DAVID. D=500, V=5, and I=1 (the first number). 'A' is the first letter of the alphabet