# A riddle for your time (4)

Tags: riddle

> 500 is at my end and my start, yet 5 is at my heart.
>   The first letter and the first number make me complete.

What is my name?

---

**Hint**

> My name is that of a king.

Comment: What's the difference to http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9315/a-real-star-riddle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My answer is:

> DAVID. D=500, V=5, and I=1 (the first number). 'A' is the first letter of the alphabet

Comment: That is correct, good job

Comment: Thanks. It was a good puzzle. I thought of Roman numerals and it was done.