# The name of the king

Tags: riddle

An easy one for you :

> Starting and ending with five hundred,
>   We find a five in its center.
>   First of all the letters
>   And first of all the numbers
>   In his name are also discovered.

Who is he?

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9315/a-real-star-riddle ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

He is

> King David

Explanation

> D is the Roman numeral for 500, so his name begins and ends in D.
>  V is the Roman numeral for 5, which is in the middle of his name.
>  The "first of all letters" is A and "the first of all numbers" is I (again in Roman numerals).
>
>  Putting it together you get DAVID.

Comment: Fast and clear. Good job !